# Read/write to AWS S3 from Apache Spark Kubernetes container via vpc endpoint giving 400 Bad Request

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, kubernetes, amazon-s3, pyspark

I am trying to read and write data to AWS S3 from Apache Spark Kubernetes Containervia vpc endpoint
The Kubernetes container is on premise (data center) in US region . Following is the Pyspark code to connect to S3:

```
from pyspark.conf import SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

conf = (
        SparkConf()
        .setAppName("PySpark S3 Example")
        .set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.endpoint.region", "us-east-1")
        .set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.endpoint","<vpc-endpoint>")
        .set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key", "<access_key>")
        .set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key", "<secret_key>")
        .set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")
        .set("spark.driver.extraJavaOptions", "-Dcom.amazonaws.services.s3.enforceV4=true")
        .set("spark.executor.extraJavaOptions","-Dcom.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4=true")
        .set("spark.executor.extraJavaOptions", "-Dcom.amazonaws.services.s3.enforceV4=true")
        .set("spark.fs.s3a.path.style.access", "true")
        .set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.server-side-encryption-algorithm","SSE-KMS")
        .set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.SimpleAWSCredentialsProvider")
    )

spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf=conf).getOrCreate()

data = [{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}, {"key1":"val1","key2":"val2"}]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data)

df.write.format("json").mode("append").save("s3a://<bucket-name>/test/")
```

Exception Raised:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o91.save.
: org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.AWSBadRequestException: doesBucketExist on <bucket-name>
: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Bad Request (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: 400 Bad Request; Request ID: <requestID>;
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: It works through the gateway endpoint but not through the vpc endpoint. Also, the aws cli command works like a charm through the vpc endpoint. So all routes from vpce to s3 are created and working

Answer (score 0):

unless your hadoop s3a client is region aware (3.3.1+), setting that region option won't work. There's an aws sdk option `"aws.region` which you can set as as a system property instead.

Comment: this option is not making any difference. we even tried with the latest version (3.3.2) of aws-hadoop jars, we are still not able to connect to s3 from spark job (pyspark) via vpc endpoint

Comment: intersting. 3.3.2 takes "fs.s3a.region" as a hadoop config option, which will work

Comment: its working with latest spark version 3.3.0 and latest hadoop-aws jars